# Is this linearisation of the uncapacitated facility location problem correct?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

> Assume we have $n$ factories with unlimited capacity that produce a certain product. The costs to build the factories are $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ respectively. There are $m$ clients whose demands for this product are $d_1, \ldots, d_m$ units respectively. We also have $e_{ij}$ is the cost to deliver $1$ unit from factory $i$ to client $j$. The total cost is the sum of building cost and delivery cost. Determine which factories should we build to minimize the total cost.

This is known as *uncapacitated facility location* problem. Could you please verify if my linearisation of the product $x_i y_{ij}$ of a binary variable $x_i$ and a continuous $y_i$ is correct?

---

Let $x_i = 1$ if the factory $i$ is built and $0$ otherwise. Let $y_{ij}$ be the proportion of $d_j$ supplied by factory $i$. To simplify notation, let $[m] := \{1, \ldots m\}$ and $[n] := \{1, \ldots n\}$. Then our problem becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{min} & \quad \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n d_j e_{ij} x_i y_{ij}\\
\text{s.t} & \quad x_i \in \{0, 1\}  && \text{for all} \quad i \in [n] \\
           & \quad y_{ij} \in [0, 1]  && \text{for all} \quad (i, j) \in [n] \times [m] \\
           & \quad \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_{ij}= 1 && \text{for all} \quad j \in [m]
\end{aligned}
$$

Then I want to linearise this optimisation problem as follows. Let $z_{ij} := x_i y_{ij}$. Then our problem becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{min} & \quad \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n d_j e_{ij} z_{ij}\\
\text{s.t} & \quad x_i \in \{0, 1\}  && \text{for all} \quad i \in [n] \\
           & \quad z_{ij} \in [0, 1]  && \text{for all} \quad (i, j) \in [n] \times [m] \\
           & \quad \sum_{i=1}^n z_{ij}= 1 && \text{for all} \quad j \in [m]
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you @quasi. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but not quite.

To see that your reformulation is not correct, note that if we have $c_i > 0$ for all $i$, then any optimal solution of your reformulated version will have $x_i=0$ for all $i$, hence the minimum possible value for your reformulated version will be less than the minimum possible value for the original version.

As a way to fix it, you can include the constraints $z_{ij}\le x_i$ for all $i,j$ in order to guarantee $z_{ij}=0$ whenever $x_i=0$.

But note: Since the variables $x_i$ are binary, you have a mixed-integer linear program, not a linear program.